# xslt .net and date diffs

Tags: xslt, date, diff

Using .net XsltCompiled transforms, whats the best way to perform date diffs?

Is defining a C# code snippet via the ms:script CDATA block "good enough"? or is moving to a different transform engine worth it i.e. Saxon?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Are you more curious about diffs or transformations?

Comment: Date Diff's are the focus of the question.

Comment: Be sure to let the XML team at Microsoft know that not having XSLT2/XPath2 has cost you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# code snippet via the ms:script CDATA block is good enough for simple date comparison. You can also build XSLT helper in C# http://snipplr.com/view/17080/xslt-helper-class/ or take a look EXSLT - Dates and Times covers date and time-related extension elements and functions http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html